# Aptana 'contest assist' not displaying classes?

Tags: aptana, content-assist

I am new to Aptana Studio and I'm having some difficulty with the 'Content Assist' while trying to write CSS. I have some tags that are identified by classes and id's in my HTML. However, when I go to write the styles in my styles no content assist appears when I type `.` or `#`. I know there should be something because the Lynda video I'm watching has a dialog appear to help with available classes and id's to choose from.

Am I doing something wrong here? I have all the browsers/user agents for all project natures in preferences set up. In editors I have `.#:` for 'display proposals'.

Thank you for any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the "Web" nature to your project.

To do that, right-click on the workspace icon in the Workspaces list (in the default perspective it's on the left) and select Properties. In the "Project Natures" options check the "Web" box and rebuild.

Comment: Easy, but it definitely saved me lots of precious time. Thanks!